# Objected is lost when being placed in operator overload + statement

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am creating a string class for school that holds 2 data types, an int length and a char* buf.

One of the constructors requires me to overload the + operator.

```
String s10("DEF");
String t10('H');
String u10("ABC" + s10 + "G" + t10 + 'I');
```

I overloaded the + operator with the following code

```
String& operator + (const String& s1, const String& s2){

String equals;
equals.length = s1.length + s2.length;
equals.buf = new char[equals.length + NULL_OFFSET];
strcpy(equals.buf, s1.buf);
strcat(equals.buf, s2.buf);
return equals;
}
```

When String u10 is called, it successfully combines the 2 String objects and returns them in String equals.

But when equals goes to be + with "G" its memory address is lost(or maybe it is deleted I am not sure)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are returning a non-`const` reference to a local variable allocated on stack, which becomes invalid when exiting the scope of declaration.

But there is no reason to return a reference, `operator+` is supposed to return a value, not a reference to a value:

```
String operator+(constr String& s1, const String& s2)
```

so that you are returning a whole new object, which is what you would expect from a binary `+` operator, a reference is something that alias an existing object, which is not the case in this situation.

A situation in which it would be used is in `operator+=` which indeed should return a `String&` since you are effectively modifying the left-hand value of the operator.

Comment: I have been stuck on that all day. Thank you very much!